# Subdomains Always Redirect To Main Domain - Apache2 VirtualHosts & Debain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, subdomain, virtualhost

I want to set up a main site, and a sub-domain for development, using apache2 VirtualHosts. This is what my site.conf virtual host file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dev.mysite.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/site/subdomain
        <Directory /var/www/site/subdomain >
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        ServerAlias mysite.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/site/main
        <Directory /var/www/site/main >
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that every time I visit dev.mysite.com, I just get mysite.com.

There's no htaccess for the main site, and the .htaccess for the sub-domain looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried all the other solutions I could find (using literal IPs, re-ordering things, using ports instead of named hosts)... I'm totally stuck now. The site is enabled of course.  Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Wordpress Was The Problem

Or rather, me not knowing that I had to configure the Wordpress site url to be the subdomain, otherwise it would just redirect to the domain given...

So the solution: open the `wp_options` table and edit the site_url to include the subdomain.

Comment: This helped me a lot, been looking at apache & debian settings for hours.